# complex vector dependency over $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I'm having problems with this one, hoping you can help me and others in the process:

given the following subgroup: $A=\{(1+i,1,-2i),(1,1-i,2+i),(2+i,2,-3)\} $- is it linear dependent when you look at $\mathbb{C}^2$ over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$?

what I did:
$$a(1+i)+b+c(2+i)=0$$
$$a+b(1-i)+2c=0$$
$$a(-2i)+b(2+i)-c=0$$
But for some reason I did not find a linear dependency and I don't know what I did wrong.
I think that in order for the vector to be linear dependent over $\mathbb R$, the IMG should equal to zero, so we are left only with objects of $\mathbb R$.

hoping you can help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: You could apply Gauss elimination.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is right. Maybe you write the equation with a matrix and vectors, which makes it more clear.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1+i & 1 & 2+i\\1 & 1-i & 2\\-2i & 2+i & -1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
If the matrix is invertable, then $A$ contains linear independent vectors over $\mathbb{C}$ and over $\mathbb{R}$.

If the matrix is not invertable, then $A$ contains linear dependent vectors over $\mathbb{C}$. To check if they are linear dependent over $\mathbb{R}$, you have to compute the kernel of the matrix over $\mathbb{R}$. If the kernel over $\mathbb{R}$
contains at least one element in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then it $A$ is lineare dependent over $\mathbb{R}$. If the kernel over $\mathbb{R}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}^3\setminus \mathbb{R}^3$, then $A$ is lineare dependent over $\mathbb{C}$ but not over $\mathbb{R}$.

> If you check the determinant of the matrix, you get $2$ and therefore it is invertible. $A$ contains just linear independent vectors of $\mathbb{C}^3$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$.